# Can you check the bind file edit history, or edit it directly just like .bashrc?

Tags: bind

Sometimes when I change to a fresh install, I'd like to know of any shortcuts I may have forgotten to port over; that way when I change computers I can quickly port my bind file preferences over. I'd like to know if there's any history keeping of users changing their `bind` to anything from default linux. Or if I could just simply export my bind file from my old computer and do the diff with the new one and check for changes myself.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer: No

There is nothing pre-installed. There is nothing that you can do after they are changed.

## Long answer: Yes. Install a revision control system, and use it.

You did not say where the files are.

### For `/etc`

Use etc keeper, with another revision control system (it is not a revision control system but it uses one to keep track of what is happening in `/etc`, and integrates with the package manager, so keeps notes of what you have changed and what the package manager has changed.

### For other files

Use a revision control tool: such as mercurial. Some will tell you to use `git`, but it is hard to use. There is also subversion.